# eigenvalues of $A^TA$ and $AA$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am a little bit confused about such fundamental problems:

Suppose
1. $Ax=\lambda x$.
2. $A \in \mathbb{R^{n \times n}} $.

Case I:   $$A^TAx = \lambda A^Tx=\lambda \lambda x=\lambda^2x$$

Case II:  $$AAx = \lambda Ax=\lambda \lambda x=\lambda^2x$$

From above, it seems that $A^TA$ and $AA$ have the same eigenvalues.

However, consider   $$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\3 & 4\end{bmatrix}$$

If checking the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ and $AA$ by matlab, they are not the same.

Why is that?

Comment: $A^Tx \neq \lambda x$ in genreal.

Comment: Consider the following:    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123923/a-matrix-and-its-transpose-have-the-same-set-of-eigenvalues

Comment: The eigenvalues are the same yet they might corresponds to different eigenvectors (not the same $x$).

Comment: How about this:   $||A||_2 = \sigma_{max}(A) = (\lambda_{max}(A^TA))^{\frac{1}{2}}$, the second part is the singular value. Does it mean, the definition of singular value comes from $A^TA$ instead of $AA$?

Comment: It seems that the singular value in general is not the eigenvalue. (They are the same when $A = A^T$).

Comment: So you can say that singular values of $A$ are square root of the eigenvalues of $AA^T$, not that of $AA$.