# what are the general form of eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, matrix-rank

could anyone help me to understand which fatal mistake is there..?
I mean, I can understand , that orthogonal matrices can have complex eigenvalues. but then, what fallacy is there in that proof ?

and a related question , can the eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix be 'zero' !

[image]

Comment: Answer to your related question : by definition, eigenvalues must be non-zero

Comment: by definition of ?

Comment: An orthogonal matrix is invertible, hence has determinant non-zero, but determinant is product of eigenvalues, so no eigenvalue is $0$. But eigenvalues CAN be $0$ for a symmetric matrix which does not have full rank.

Comment: @LandonCarter  ah i see..:)another question P is matrix of order n*n. does that mean it is either orthogonal or idempotent ?

Comment: Why will any square matrix be either orthogonal or idempotent? What about a matrix of elements $(1,2),(3,4)$?

Comment: :P sorry i did  a typo. don't mind. extremely sorry. 

P is matrix of order n*n . and $p^3=p$ . is that either idempotent or orthogonal ?

Answer (score 1):

Clarification: The "proof" assumed that $x^Tx\neq0$ and hence when we get $(\lambda^2-1)x^Tx=0$ the author of the proof concluded that $\lambda^2=1$.

However, one must remember that the proof is correct when $x$ is a vector with **real** entries. Otherwise, in general, $x^*x>0$ and not $x^Tx>0$ where $x$ is the eigenvector.

Hence, NO CONCLUSION can be drawn from this "proof". This is where the fallacy lies.

The correct method to proceed would be to consider $Qx=\lambda x$, where $x\neq0$. Then, $(Qx)^*=\bar\lambda x^*$ i.e. $x^*Q^*=\bar\lambda x^*$. Hence we have $x^*Q^*Qx=|\lambda|^2x^*x$.

Now use $Q^*Q=Q^TQ=I$ and the fact that $x^*x>0$, which shows that $|\lambda|^2=1$ and hence $|\lambda|=1$.

Comment: but here its' proved that if a matrix and it's transpose have same set of eigenvalues. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123923/a-matrix-and-its-transpose-have-the-same-set-of-eigenvalues

Comment: $\bar\lambda$ is eigenvalue of the conjugate transpose of $A$.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The fallacy is in the fact that the eigenvector has, in general, complex entries. For instance, the matrix
$$
Q=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is orthogonal, but has no real eigenvalue and no real eigenvector either.

Let's try with the eigenvalue $i$, for which a norm $1$ eigenvector is $x=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1/\sqrt{2}\\i/\sqrt{2}\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Then
$$
x^TQ^TQx=
\begin{bmatrix}i/\sqrt{2}&1/\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}i/\sqrt{2}\\1/\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}=
0
$$
and surely not $1$.

Comment: But for real eigenvalues, the theorem of the question is true.

Comment: @enzotib Yes, of course: a real matrix has real eigenvectors for its real eigenvalues.