# Does Transpose preserve eigenvalues over the complex field?

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, transpose

I understand from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/123927/308392) answer that a Matrix A and its transpose $A^T$ share the same eigenvalues. This is because the transpose operation is commutative, transpose does not change the determinant and we obtain the characteristic polynomial via the determinant.

But I was solving a problem from the ECE [GATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graduate_Aptitude_Test_in_Engineering) 2014 and it seems that A needs to have only real values in order for the eigenvalues to be the same. Since the answer is (b) as eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix can be negative.

[image: Q93]

I tried experimenting with different matrices populated with complex values and I find that the eigenvalues are the same.

[image: example]

[image: exampleT]

Right now I am guessing that when we consider all complex matrices, $A^T$ means A conjugate transpose and not simply transpose. So in the question, they meant $\bar A^T$. In which case,

$$\det(A^{T} - \lambda I) = \det((A - \bar \lambda I)^{T})  = \det (A - \bar \lambda I)$$

So my understanding is that the transpose operation causes the eigenvalues to be conjugated.

My examples also show the same result.

[image: conjugateT]

---

**So what is the answer to the GATE question no. 93? Why is (c) not the answer?**

Comment: Since $\det A = \det A^T$, you see that $\det (\lambda I -A) = \det (\lambda I -A^T)$. Hence the eigenvalues are the same. No need for $A$ to be real.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because statement (c) is true, as well as statements (a) and (d). Only (b) is false (take $-\operatorname{Id}$, for instance).

And transpose means transpose over whatever field you're working with. Conjugate transpose is another thing.

Comment: I mean, why does A have to be real. Why can't A be complex and still $A^T$ seems to have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: At no point it is written that it **has** to be real. If, instead of “real”, it was written that the matrix was “rational”, it would still be true.

Comment: So if (c) was "If A is complex, the eigen values of A and $A^T$ are always the same", even then (c) would be true?

Comment: Yes. And if, instead of complex matrices, we were working with matrices over the field of rational functions in $10$ variables over $\mathbb C$, it would **still** be true.