# How can you prove a matrix has the same eigenvalues as its transpose without using determinants?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I know a matrix has the same eigenvalues as its transpose, but is there a way to see this in line with Axler (i.e. without bringing in determinants)?

Comment: Why ? What's wrong with bringing in determinants ?

Comment: @Potato "Once determinants have been banished to the end
of the book, a new route opens to the main goal of linear algebra—
understanding the structure of linear operators." - from Linear algebra done right.

Comment: Axler doesn't use them, and I'm using his textbook, so, I just want to like, reconcile this result with it.

Comment: What [properties of the transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose#Properties) are you allowed to assume?

Comment: @Dan Any of the ones in that list are fine

Comment: @Jnrn: Well, I assume you mean to exclude #5 (which brings in determinants) and #9 (which is what you want to prove).

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/877416/721644).

Comment: In support of the Answers posted below, the general result that *row rank = column rank* can be useful here.

Answer (score 6):

The eigenvalues of $M$ are the numbers $\lambda$ such that $M - \lambda I$ has non-trivial kernel, i.e. the numbers for which the square matrix $M-\lambda I$ cannot be inverted. But $$(M-\lambda I)^T = M^T - \lambda I^T = M^T-\lambda I$$

and so if $M - \lambda I$ is not invertible, $(M-\lambda I)^T$ is not invertible either, as a square matrix is invertible if and only if its transpose is (thanks to Marc for the suggestions!). But the above shows that $\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue for $M^T$, as we wanted to show.

Comment: I have difficulty seeing how exactly your third sentence uses the second one (maybe because I don't know if you define a cokernel using the transpose matrix, or using the dual vector space, or as quotient by the image subspace. Wouldn't it be easier to say that $M-\lambda I$ is invertible if and only if its transpose is (which happens if and only if either has trivial kernel)?

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I'll update the answer to reflect it. I'm implicitly using a bunch of identifications that I can just skip if I do it that way.

Answer (score 2):

The eigenvalues of a square matrix $A$ are the roots of its minimal polynomial. Since for any polynomial $P\in K[X]$ the matrix $P[A^\top]$ is the transpose of $P[A]$, and one of these is zero if and only if the other is, the matrices $A$ and its transpose $A^\top$ have the same minimal polynomials. Therefore they have the same eigenvalues.

Or even simpler, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if $A-\lambda I$ fails to be invertible, which happens if and only if it transpose $A^\top-\lambda I$ fails to be invertible (because clearly if some square matrix $M$ has an inverse, the transpose of that inverse will be an inverse of $M^\top$, and vice versa).