# Does turning a matrix upside down preserve its eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The matrix

$$\left( \begin{array}{} -6 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 \end{array} \right)$$

has eigenvalues of -7 and 6. If you turn this matrix upside down,

$$\left( \begin{array}{} 5 & 4 \\ 3 & -6 \end{array} \right)$$

It still has eigenvalues of -7 and 6. Does this happen for any matrix?

Note: I am not asking about a rotation matrix. I'm literally rotating the matrix itself.

Here's an alternate way of stating the problem I came up with while trying to solve this.

You have an arbitrary $n$ by $n$ matrix A. You also have the [exchange matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchange_matrix) $J_n$.

$$J_n=\left( \begin{array}{} 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \ldots & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots \\ 0 & 1 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{array} \right)$$

Then, multiply A by $J_n$ on both sides to get $B$.

$$B = J_n A J_n$$

Do $A$ and $B$ always have the same eigenvalues? If so, why?

Note: I do not care about whether the matrices have the same eigenvectors.

See also:

- [A matrix and its transpose have the same set of eigenvalues/other version: $A$ and $A^T$ have the same spectrum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123923/a-matrix-and-its-transpose-have-the-same-set-of-eigenvalues-other-version-a-a)

Comment: I believe this, or something very close to it, is a problem in Trefethen and Bao. Right. Prob. 4.2: Suppose $A$ is an m x n matrix and B is obtained by rotating $A$ 90 degrees clockwise on paper. Do $A$ and $B$ have the same singular values? Prove that the answer is yes or give a counterexample. Of course, you're going with 180 degrees, and asking about eigenvalues ... but it sure feels like the same problem in a different set of clothes.

Comment: Say $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then $(J_nAJ_n)(J_nx) = J_nAx = \lambda (J_nx)$.

Comment: $J_n^{-1}=J_n$, and [similar matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) have the same eigenvalues.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, good spot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $J_n^{-1}=J_n$, the two matrices $A$ and the rotated one $B$ are similar:
$$
B=SAS^{-1}
$$
with $S=J_n$.
Hence they have the same characteristic polynomial. So the eigenvalues agree.