# Same characteristic polynomial $\iff$ same eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, alternative-proof, proof-explanation

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/87705/53259) proves: Similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial. (Lay P277 Theorem 4)

I prefer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8407/53259, but this proves that they have the same eigenvalues.

Are they equivalent? What about in general, even for matrices which are NOT similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If $A$ and $B$ have the same characteristic polynomial, then clearly the have the same eigenvalues, these are the zeros of the characteristic polynomial.
2. The converse is generally not true: for example
   $$
   A=\left[\matrix{1&0&0\cr
   0&0&1\cr 0&0&0}\right],\quad
   B=\left[\matrix{1&1&0\cr
   0&1&0\cr 0&0&0}\right]
   $$
   we have $\sigma(A)=\sigma(B)=\{0,1\}$, but $\chi_A(X)=X^2(X-1)$,  $\chi_B(X)=X(X-1)^2$.

Comment: Of course, if two matrices have the same eigenvalues with the same multiplicities (and we work over an algebraically closed field) then the matrices do have the same characteristic polynomial.

Comment: How did you get to the statement that if A and B have the same eigenvalues and multiplicities, then they have the same characteristic polynomial?

Answer (score 0):

"What about in general, even for matrices which are NOT similar?"
You can get matrices A and B, jordan matrices, with the same characteristic polynomial and same eigenvalues and the matrices ARE NOT EQUIVALENT Jordan matrices.