# proof-similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87699/elegant-proofs-that-similar-matrices-have-the-same-characteristic-polynomial) but did not understand the following step:
$$ \det(xI - M^{-1} A M)= \det(M^{-1} xI M - M^{-1} A M)$$

The author said in the comments that it is due to "$xM$ commutes with the identity matrix $I$"

What does it mean?

Comment: I think what they mean is $xIM = MxI$. Similar to $x+y=y+x$. See commutativity-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the text should say that $xI$ (the matrix with $x$ on the diagonal and zeros elsewhere) commutes with $M$, since that is what is being used. Indeed once you know this fact you have
$$
  M^{-1}(xI)M=M^{-1}M(xI)=xI
$$
which is what is (in the opposite direction) used. But the fact that $xI$ commutes with $M$ is obvious: computing $(xI)M$ means multiplying every row of $M$ by the indeterminate $x$, while computing $M(xI)$ means multiplying every column of $M$ by the indeterminate $x$, which obviously has the same result.

Comment: So generally speaking, we can say that both the Identity matrix and the scalar matrix are commutative with any matrix

Comment: @gbox: Yes that is true. Although I might pedantically add to the statement about scalar matrices "as long as scalars themselves commute". If ever you consider matrices over non-commutative rings (which is perfectly possible) then "scalar matrices" no longer always commute, because left-multiplication by a given scalar may be different from right-multiplication by it. But then scalar matrices are not a very useful notion is such a setting to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ commutes with $B$ if $AB=BA$. In this case, you have $$(xM)I = x(MI) = xM=x(IM)=I(xM)$$

so $xM$ commutes with $I$.

Because it commutes, you have $$xI=xI\cdot I = x(M^{-1}M)I =xM^{-1}(MI) = xM^{-1} IM=M^{-1}xI M$$

Comment: On the last step we could bring $x$ inside the expression as it is a scalar?

Comment: @gbox Yes, you can plug in a scalar anywhere. If $a$ is a scalar and $A,B$ are matrices, then $a(AB)=(aA)B=A(aB)$

Comment: This looks needlessly complicated to me. Why not just $(xM)I=xM=I(xM)$? Also your second display never uses commutation of $xM$ with $I$, indeed it never even forms $xM$ to begin with. Instead it uses the (unproved here) fact that $(xA)B=A(xB)$, with $A=M^{-1}$ and $B=I$.

Comment: What Marc says is also what I thought when I first saw the question. Attributing the equality $M^{-1}xIM=xI$ to the fact that $I$ commutes with every square matrix is just wrong. To prove this equality, one can use the fact that $xI$ commutes with $M$, but not the fact that $I$ commutes with $xM$. At any rate, proving the equality using commutativity is unnatural. What matters here is actually --- as Marc says --- another fact, namely, $(xA)B=A(xB)$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I agree, I now think my answer is bad... I hope OP accepts the better answer that you gave so I can delete mine.