# Matrix and it's Transpose have the same eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

I have the following question in my book for mathematics: "Show that $A\in M_{n\times n}$has the same eigenvalues as $A^\tau$.

I can see how to do this for a $1\times 1,\ 2\times 2$, etc.

I would just always calculate the characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)$, where $p(\lambda) = \det (A - \lambda I)$ and than solve for $\lambda$.

Now I can't really wrap my head around how to do this for a general $n\times n$ matrix. I think this would probably involve induction over $n$, but I'm not really sure how and how to get even started.

Comment: How does the characteristic polynomial look for the transposed matrix?

Comment: isn't it exactly the same, since $det(A) = det(A^T)$?

Comment: **Any square matrix is similar to its transpose and similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial.**

Comment: The problem is already solved thanks to Anurag A. , I will take a look at the suggested question later.

Comment: @Matthias, it has already been solved before, you only have to search. It is your duty to see the "suggested" question.

Comment: [Elegant proofs that similar matrices have the same characteristic polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/87699/721644).  Furthermore: [A matrix and its transpose have the same set of eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/123923/721644).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\det\left(A^T-cI\right) & = \det\left(A^T-cI^T\right) &(\because I^T=I)\\
& =\det(A-cI)^T\\
&=\det(A-cI) & (\because \det(M)=\det\left(M^T\right)) 
\end{align*}
So the characteristic polynomials are same.

Comment: Could you also explain what the three dots are, I have never seen them before?

Comment: @MatthiasK. It means "since" or "because"

Comment: Oh ok, than this explains it very well and easy, thank you!

Comment: @AnuragA This question has already been [answered by @Fretty](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/123927/705917)