# Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$, $A^2=0$. Prove that $\det(tI-A)=t^2$ for any scalar $t$ (Without the use of Cayley Hamilton theorem).

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I tried alot of stuff and went far as taking a general $A$ matrix and trying to apply it and I feel that I'm missing something and I'm not in the right direction.

 Note that I would be happy to get all types of answers but this question is intended to be solved using determinant properties. 
 Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.
EDIT: I have not learnt Cayley-Hamliton theorem yet, and looking for a solution without it.

Comment: Do you know the Cayley-Hamilton theorem? Anyway, show that $tI-A$ is always invertible if $t \neq 0$.

Comment: @Mindlack No I don't

Comment: @Pwaol Google it. This is designed to be solved with it.

Comment: All you've told us is "solve using determinant properties".  Everything else you say is not telling us anything in the way of context.  *Show us what you claim you tried* (Everything? then you should have a lot of work to show us!)

Comment: Okay let me clear myself more, seems like this can be trivially solved using Cayley Hamilton theorem and I got it as a question before I even learnt it, so what ways would be to proof it without knowing the theorem? is it just by going far and taking a general matrix?

Comment: @Pwaol It's a bit involved without Cayley Hamilton. I can't imagine this problem would be assigned to novice linear algebraists without Cayley Hamilton.

Comment: @DonThousand I see, this might be the reason that it's only for $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: I can push you in the right direction: name $A$ as $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$. Then $A^2=0$ is 4 equations for $a,b,c,d$ and write $\det(tI-A)$ explicitly in $a,b,c,d$. Analyse.

Comment: @A.Γ. Thank you :)

Comment: @Pwaol can you edit your question to say that you haven't learned C-H yet and want a solution without it?

Comment: @TrevorGunn sure I can, should I edit the title? or the body or it doesn't matter?

Comment: The title might be a bit crowded but if it will fit then sure. Definitely in the body though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\det \begin{pmatrix} t - a & -b \\ -c & t - d \end{pmatrix} = t^2 - (a + d)t + (ad - bc)$$

Since $A^2 = 0$, we have $ad - bc = 0$.

If $a + d \neq 0$ then setting $t = a + d$ we have that $\det(tI - A) = 0$. On the other hand,

$$ (tI - A)(\alpha I + \beta A) = I$$

has a solution (try to find it). So $tI - A$ is invertible if $t \neq 0$. But then $a + d$ cannot be non-zero.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the small *size* of the matrix $A$.

All you need is to work out the following cases by hand:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0\\0&0
\end{pmatrix},\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\0&0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Once you work out the simple cases, find a [relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/87699) between $\det(tI-J)$ and $\det(tI-BJB^{-1})$ and show that you can write $A$ as $A=BJB^{-1}$ for some matrix $B$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is yet another way to show it:
In some extension field (in this case we can just take $\Bbb C$ of course) the characteristic polynomial $\det(xI-A)$ will split into linear factors. Let $\lambda\in\Bbb C$ be any zero of it, i.e. $\det(\lambda I-A)=0$. Then $\lambda I-A$ is not invertible, hence there is a $v\in\Bbb C^2$ (an 'eigenvector') with $v\ne0$ and $(\lambda I-A)v=0$. So we get $Av=\lambda v$. Applying $A$ again gives us $$0=A^2v=A\lambda v=\lambda^2 v$$ Therefore $\lambda^2=0\Rightarrow \lambda=0$. Hence $\det(xI-A)$ has only one zero in $\Bbb C$, namely $0$ (not counting multiplicity). Therefore $\det(xI-A)=x^2$.
Of course this proof generalizes immediately to higher dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

If $A^2=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}=\pmatrix{a^2+bc&b(a+d)\\c(a+d)&bc+d^2}=\pmatrix{0&0\\0&0},$

then $b=0$, in which case $a=d=0$, or $b\ne0$, in which case $a=-d$ and $c=\dfrac{-a^2}b$,

so $A=\pmatrix{0&0\\c&0}$ or $A=\pmatrix{a&b\\\dfrac{-a^2}b&-a}$.

Can you take it from here and compute $\det(tI-A)$ now?